# Apache RewriteRule Regex Issue

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html says:

In mod_rewrite the `!` character can be used before a regular expression to negate it. This is, a string will be considered to have matched only if it does not match the rest of the expression.

However, my config only works for the first rule but not the second. Can someone tell me why?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(/global/.*)$ /dir1
RewriteRule !^(/global/.*)$ /dir2    #this rule doesn't work.
```

Comment: Why don't you use .* instead since your second regex will match anything that hasn't been matched by the first regex?

Comment: `RewriteCond` only applies to the immediate rule above it. Is this your intended behaviour? Also, if you set the `[L]` flag on the `/dir1` redirect, then you can use @flec's suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the URL against which the second rule doesn't work? And where is this rule used (.htaccess or httpd.conf)?

Comment: I tried @flec's suggestion. It works for host.example.com but example.com/uri will also be rewriten. This is not what I want. I basically have a wildcard domain config for *.example.com, and I only want to rewrite host.example.com. The other urls will still go to the DocumentRoot.

Comment: I'm using the rules in a virtualhost section (not in .htaccess). <VirtualHost example.com:80> ServerName example.com ... </VirtualHost>. *.example.com is pointed to example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've got this worked by splitting rules into two. both host.example.com and example.com work fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(/global/.*)$ /dir1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir2 [L]
```

**However I still want to know how we can use "!" in RewriteRule.**